# Netgear ProSafe with Cisco Aironet - Guest VLAN no Internet

Tags: networking, routing, vlan, switching

I'm running into an issue setting up a guest VLAN on my Netgear Prosafe switch using a Cisco Aironet 1832i Access Point. The Management VLAN works as expected (issues IP addresses, can access Internet, etc.). **However, the guest VLAN 20 can't access the internet.** I think it may be some setting/security issue I'm missing. Also note that VLAN 20 cannot ping VLAN 1 addresses.

Any ideas?

-

**Comcast Internet Details**

- Comcast Router (Arris)
- Gateway: 10.0.0.1
- DHCP Range: 10.0.0.2 -> 10.0.0.125

I've setup the AP as a Controller via Mobile Express with the below settings:

**Management VLAN**

- VLAN Management (1)
- WLAN SSID: Test
- WPA2
- VLAN Tagging: No (assumes 1)
- DHCP: day0-mgmt
- VLAN: Management Network (1)
- Network/Mask: 10.0.0.0 / 255.255.255.0
- Start/End IP: 10.0.0.160 / 10.0.0.185
- Default Gateway: 10.0.0.1
- DHCP Server: 10.0.0.185

**Guest VLAN**

- VLAN 20
- WLAN SSID: Guest
- Open
- VLAN Tagging: Yes, 20
- DHCP: day0-testGuest
- VLAN: 20
- Network/Mask: 10.0.2.0 / 255.255.255.0
- Start/End IP: 10.0.2.1 / 10.0.2.250
- Default Gateway: 10.0.2.1
- DHCP Server: 10.0.2.250

The issue comes in with the Netgear ProSafe Switch (I think...). Here is how I've got it configured:

**SWITCH -> Netgear ProSafe GS516TP**
IP 10.0.0.12
Subnet 255.255.255.0
Firmware 6.0.1.16

- Port 1: Comcast Router (Internet)
- Port 5: Cisco Aironet Access Point #1 (Controller)

Configuration

- Switching > VLAN > Basic > VLAN: Added VLAN ID: 20 w/ name Guest
- Switching > VLAN > Advanced > VLAN Membership: Ports 1 & 5 set to "T" for VLAN ID 20
- Switching > VLAN > Advanced > Port PVID Configuration: ports 1 & 5 set "Ingress Filtering = Disabled" left PVID = 1
- Routing > VLAN > VLAN Routing > VLAN 20 / IP Address: 10.0.2.1 (Default Gateway for VLAN 20 DHCP) / Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
- *Note: Before this the ARP table showed only VLAN 1 (mgmt), after adding 10.0.2.1 it showed all active clients*
- Security > Port Authentication > 802.1x Config: Port Based Auth & Guest VLAN = Disabled (default)
- Security > Port Auth > Advanced > Port Auth = All Ports = Authorized w/ Guest VLAN Disable